# proof-explaination : $\forall x~(P (x ) ∧ Q(x )) \equiv \forall x~P (x )~ \wedge ~\forall x~Q(x )$

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

The following content is from a book: Rosen discrete mathematics and I understand most of it.   But, why can we conclude that $P(a)$ and $Q(a)$ is true for **every element** in the domain ?   Why **every element**?   Because I always have this intuition that "a" is a single element.   Is it because "a" is a variable?   Can someone explain the reasoning behind?

> **Content**: suppose that $\forall x~(P(x) \wedge Q(x))$ is true.   This means that if $a$ is in the domain, then $P(a)\wedge Q(a)$ is true.   Hence, $P(a)$ is true and $Q(a)$ is true.   Because $P(a)$ is true and $Q(a)$ is true for every element in the domain, we can conclude that $\forall x~P(x)$ and $\forall x~Q(x)$ are both true.   This means that $\forall x~P(x)~\wedge~\forall x~Q(x)$ is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conclude that because $a$ is an *arbitrary* element of the domain. Because of the universal quantifier in the first statement, $P(a)$ is true for any element $a$ of the domain and we can deduce $\forall x P(x).$

The formal rule is called [universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization): From $\phi(x),$ conclude $\forall x\phi(x).$

Comment: Thank you for leading me to the right point. I found this discussion particularly helpful ! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889107/why-does-universal-generalization-work-the-rule-of-inference